# Can I generate a list using the function with an iterator argument?

Tags: python, iterator

For example, I have a function called addone.

```
def addone(num):
    num = num + 1
    return num
```

I also have a list of numbers. I want to add one to all of them.

I tried to write my code like this:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]

newlist = addone([i for i in mylist])
```

But it doesn't work.

Actually my function is much more complicated, that's why I want to use an iterator as the argument.

Does anyone think of any good idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want `[addone(i) for i in mylist]`. Also, check out `map()`. You can cast the result to a list if you want: `list(map(addone, mylist))`.

Comment: `addone` expects a number as argument (anything that supports `+ 1`). You are passing it an list, so yes it won't work. What you want to do is apply that function to each element in the list.